# Angular 2 view is not updating when variable is changed in ts

Tags: angular

Can you please tell me why my value in the html does not change when my variable gets updated? This is my code in the ts

```
private peer: any;
private anotherId: 'opopo'
public myPeerId: '123456';
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.peer = new Peer();

    this.peer.on('open', function (connectionId) {
      this.myPeerId = connectionId;
      console.log(this.myPeerId)
    });
  }
```

I can log my variable value when it changes but somehow, my html does not. Please see my html code

```
<h1>My id - {{myPeerId}}</h1>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="anotherId" >
<button (click)="connect()">Connect</button>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the console, you will see an error similar to

> Cannot read property 'myPeerId' of undefined

To refer to the class scope using `this` keyword in callbacks, use arrow function notation

```js
this.peer.on('open', (connectionId) => {     // <-- arrow notation here
  this.myPeerId = connectionId;
  console.log(this.myPeerId)
});
```